# how to fix lvalue vs rvalue compile error when using std::function and templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functional-programming

**BACKGROUND**

I have a snippet of code that compiles fine for two different invocations.

But when I try a third invocation using a `std::function<>` I get the following compile error:

`error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’`

*What does this error mean in this context and how do I code around it?*

Trying to compile the snippet below is probably the easiest way to see what's going on.

**CODE**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using format_f = std::function<std::ios_base&( std::ios_base& os )>;

enum class eBOOK_FORMAT
{
        LEFT_TO_RIGHT, RIGHT_TO_LEFT, TOP_DOWN
};

class Book
{
        int m_i;

public:
        Book( int i ) : m_i( i ) { }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, Book const& b )
        {
                os << b.m_i;
                return os;
        }
        static void Format( std::ios_base& os, eBOOK_FORMAT fmt )
        {
                // do stuff
        }
        static void Dump( std::ostream& os, Book& b, format_f f )
        {
                os << f << b;
        }
};

template< eBOOK_FORMAT FMT >
std::ios_base& format( std::ios_base& os )
{
        Book::Format( os, FMT );
        return os;
}

std::ios_base& foo( std::ios_base& os )
{
        return os;
}

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
        Book b( 42 );
        std::ostringstream  oss;
        // oss << foo << b;                                         // ok
        // oss << format<eBOOK_FORMAT::RIGHT_TO_LEFT> << b;         // ok
        Book::Dump( oss, b, format<eBOOK_FORMAT::RIGHT_TO_LEFT> );  // fail
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
static void Dump( std::ostream& os, Book& b, format_f f )
{
    f(os); os << b;
}
```

(Just `f(os) << b` wouldn't work since `f` returns `std::ios_base`, not `std::basic_ostream`and seeing M.M.'s answer, it's probably not exactly what you wanted to achieve)

Answer (score 1):

Output streams accept function with below signature, because they've provided an overload of `<<` operator for this type of functions:

```
std::ios_base& function( std::ios_base& os )
```

But you're passing a `std::function` which is far from that. The objects of `std::function` have `()` operator to use them *like* functions, but they are not really functions. Therefore that streams can not accept them.

Using template way instead of `std::function` is an easy fix:

```
template <typename F>
static void Dump( std::ostream& os, Book& b, F f )
{
    os << f << b;
}
```